# Order WP_Query by multiple fields, subtracting them from one another

Tags: wp-query, order

I have two custom fields for each post, `vote_up` and `vote_down`.

I know how to order by one of them, but I'm wondering how I can get the totals of both, subtract `vote_down` from `vote_up` and then display them according to the result of that calculation.

Ideas?

Comment: The easiest way might be to create a third custom field, vote_diff, and order by that. You could use a update_post_meta in a function to automatically calculate/enter the value of vote_diff when vote_up or vote_down changes. Where & how to do that will depend on where/how vote_up and vote_down are currently added/updated (plugin or theme or ....?).

Comment: @Michelle as an answer please :)

Comment: @Rarst done! I didn't know if I'd given enough detail to merit an actual answer but if you say so, it is so! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Rarst's request, as an answer instead of comment :-):

The easiest way might be to create a third custom field, vote_diff, and order by that. You could use [`update_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) in a function to automatically calculate/enter the value of vote_diff when vote_up or vote_down changes. Where & how to do that will depend on where/how vote_up and vote_down are currently added/updated (plugin or theme or ....?).

Comment: Bingo! I figured it out about a minute. :)